# How is a block hash calculated?

Tags: proof-of-work

I am trying to understand how Monero hashes blocks.

I understand there is something called a "block hashing blob" that is combined with a nonce, but how can I get the block hashing blob for a specific block?

I tried the Monero Daemon JSON API `get_block`, which has a field `blob` in the return value (Python):

```
from Crypto.Hash import keccak

hash_blob = daemon.get_block(1)["blob"]
k = keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
hash_bin = bytes.fromhex(hash_blob)
k.update(hash_bin)
print(k.hexdigest())
```

The hash blob returned for `get_block(1)["blob"]` is:

```
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
```

and running the above code for it prints:

```
e26f21cfccf0ac4297647c879be976ed427e97ce02745dbbd6385decc8af6b53
```

querying the deamon for block 1, as in `get_block(1)["header"]["hash"]`, I get hash:

```
771fbcd656ec1464d3a02ead5e18644030007a0fc664c0a964d30922821a8148
```

So, obviously this is quite different. `get_block_template` seems to produce something that could be combined with a nonce to build a valid hash, but this seems to be only for new blocks.

How do I calculate the hashes for an existing block? Some pseudocode or similar is fine, I tried to read some of the Monero C code, but it jumps around and my C/C++ is a bit limited, so couldn't quite figure it out.

I understand the block hashing blob would need things like coinbase transaction, merkle tree root, nonce, etc. But I also understand I need to combine them in a very specific way to get the exact correct hash. So first to build the block hashing blob, then to combine it with nonce..

An example for a block would be great but anything helps..

EDIT: I modified the daemon to add the block hashing blob to the get_block RPC method. With this I get the block hashing blob for block 1 as:

`0100d186c49a05418015bb9ae982a1975da7d79277c2705727a56894ba0fb246adaabb1f4632e345fc7c3052578a3816ec18ca6db2ec4f594b7c8a778caa4c52d2c1705bcbab9798a9ea7b01`

However, calling `cn_slow_hash` from pycryptonight on this does not give the correct hash:
`pycryptonight.cn_slow_hash(binascii.unhexlify(hashblob), x)`

Where `x` is the hash variant, I tried values 0-4. The block hash in the `get_block(1)` is `771fbcd656ec1464d3a02ead5e18644030007a0fc664c0a964d30922821a8148` but the value returned by variant 0 for above is `5aeebb3de73859d92f3f82fdb97286d81264ecb72a42e4b9f1e6d62eb682d7c0`.

If I run the same for height 1407480 as in question [Can't seem to reconstruct hashing blob for old block](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10663/cant-seem-to-reconstruct-hashing-blob-for-old-block), I get the same hashing blob as mentioned in that question (`0606f8e7a8ce05a5449f2dc32fff0730d58751fac5a2b9d58c59622f8a8d58d18e9886eddcdb01bb8c00006b4c34591fb7dd7d6664881f7c7e675aae7709d0acca033c6226727125c2127a17`), but hashing it does not give the same hash as given for the block. Just like in that question, not able to get the correct hash.. But also do not understand how the author of that question fixed it.

What could be wrong with the hashing I use here?

Answer (score 1):

> How is block hash calculated?

You create a block hashing blob (which is the block header, the tree root hash of the blocks transactions and a varint of the transaction count), then hash this using the RandomX<sup>1</sup> hashing algorithm.

> The hash blob returned for get_block(1)["blob"] is...

That is *not* a block hashing blob, that's the *block* blob as returned from the RPC [get_block](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_block).

> How do I calculate the hashes for an existing block?

For an existing block, obtain the block blob (per above), parse it to extract the header and transactions, construct your hashing blob (per above) and hash that.

> ...then to combine it with nonce

An *existing* block already has the nonce data, which can be in both the block header / in the miner transaction. Thus you don't need to do anything particular with the nonce data for an existing block - rather what you need is the block blob data and a way to parse it (extract the header and transactions) so you can construct a hashing blob.

<sup>1</sup> Note you need to use the correct PoW hashing algorithm based on the block height you are checking as the algorithm bas changed over time. The *current* algorithm is RandomX, but if you want to validate block 1 (which is something you mentioned) you'd need to use the original CryptoNight algorithm in that case.

**UPDATE** (based on comments below)

Note the term "block hash" can refer to either the PoW hash or the block ID (as used by block explorers etc). These use the same input data as described above but use *different* hash functions. For the latter you need to use Keccak-256.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a high-level overview. I also found a more detailed old example at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10663/cant-seem-to-reconstruct-hashing-blob-for-old-block?, and the hashing library at https://pypi.org/project/py-cryptonight/. Now just have to figure how the poster in that link finished the block hash calculation.. I am starting with the older blocks and will look at RandomX once have the older ones reconstructed.

Comment: I edited the question after modifying daemon to get the block hashing blob. Still, the hash I get does not match the block hash. Do you have any idea what could be wrong still?

Comment: How are you checking the resulting hash? You do realize the block hash (the one you see in a block explorer) is the block ID, not the PoW hash? Thus if you're trying to compare a blocks PoW hash to a block ID it will never match.

Comment: lol, no i did not realize this. i checked block.hash against the hash calculated with cn_slow_hash. from your comment and the answer at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/what-is-the-format-of-a-block-in-the-monero-blockchain I now see that keccak is used to hash the hash blob to get block id. keccak(len(hashblob)+hashblob) now gives me the exact value of "block.hash". finally i got it, thanks a lot! is there some reason to not reuse the POW hash, since it hashes the same data?

Comment: "is there some reason to not reuse the POW hash, since it hashes the same data?" <- The internal names are a giveaway I guess: cn_slow_hash vs cn_fast_hash.